# AngularJS remember DOM state between views

Tags: jquery, angularjs, angularjs-view

It seems like Angular re-renders an entire view when a route changes. See this example: http://jsfiddle.net/RSHG8/1/

html:

```
<div class="nav">
    <a href="#/one">One</a><a href="#/two">Two</a>
</div>
<div ng-app="app" id="ng-app">
    <div ng-view=ng-view></div>
</div>

var app = angular.module('app', []);
```

js:

```
app.config(function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when('/one', {
        template: 'Template {{template}}<br>Enter some text: <input type="text" /> then click "Two"',
        controller: 'one'
    })
        .when('/two', {
        template: 'Template {{template}}<br>Click back to view "One" to see changes undone',
        controller: 'two'
    })
        .otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/one'
    });
});

app.controller("one", function ($scope) {
    $scope.template = "One";
});

app.controller("two", function ($scope) {
    $scope.template = "Two";
});
```

Text entered by the user is forgotten when the switching between views. This will be a problem with non-angular stuff too. E.g. a jQuery expand-collapse plugin. If a user expands a certain number of elements, leaves the view and comes back, the state will be reset to everything collapsed.

Is it possible to get Angular to simple show / hide views, rather than wipe an re-render when routes change?

Comment: sure. but not with ng-view. you may use ng-show and show only the part of your page that should be visible

Comment: Would I need a top level controller that controls what view to show / hide, then controllers for each of the views?

Comment: yes, this would be a way...

Comment: I use `ui-router` to solve this problem

Comment: I created a little demo for you to check: http://plnkr.co/edit/i2OTfWQrhkCi0pztH4ns?p=preview

Comment: @IlanFrumer  - place an input onto one of the views and you'll see the contents gets wiped out if view is changed.
Here is what I have using ng-show. Would this be "valid angular"? http://jsfiddle.net/RSHG8/8/

Comment: @Fergal The trick is to keep the model on the parent state. You can also implement a persistent layer with a service. I do that with localStorage, my model is persisted even if the user reload the browser. Check again: http://plnkr.co/edit/i2OTfWQrhkCi0pztH4ns?p=preview

Comment: That only works because the input box is bound to the model. My question states that I want the state of the dom to be maintained, event if non-angular stuff is happening. i.e. if you have an input box that angular doesn't track, and the user fills it in, the contents will be removed when the view re-renders.

Comment: First, What's bad with persisting data to a view model , If you want to save it to a localstorage you must do it anyway. More, the `ngShow` hack is only acceptable with very few views. If you have a big application you cannot afford keeping that much of DOM elements and also `$watchers` is a big issue. I can create a `ngRoute` enhanced version with option to preserve the view but I don't see a real use case.

Comment: BTW, I'm working on an angular service which (lazily) creates shadow DOM elements and provides API for directives to reuse them and bind them to plugins. I need it because tons of plugins leak to memory and not providing any api for unloading them. This could also help to preserve state of some components like you need.

Answer (score 0):

You can try assigning a ng-model to the input tag and store the value in a parent controller.

HTML

```
<div class="nav">
    <a href="#/one">One</a><a href="#/two">Two</a>
</div>
<div ng-app="app" id="ng-app">
    <div controller="AppCtrl">
        <div ng-view=ng-view></div>
    </div>
</div>

var app = angular.module('app', []);
```

JS

```
app.config(function ($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider.when('/one', {
            template: 'Template {{template}}<br>Enter some text: <input type="text" ng-model="$parent.inputValue" /> then click "Two"',
            controller: 'one'
        })
            .when('/two', {
            template: 'Template {{template}}<br>Click back to view "One" to see changes undone',
            controller: 'two'
        })
            .otherwise({
            redirectTo: '/one'
        });
    });

    app.controller("AppCtrl", function AppCtrl($scope) {
        $scope.inputValue = "";
    });

    app.controller("one", function ($scope) {
        $scope.template = "One";
    });

    app.controller("two", function ($scope) {
        $scope.template = "Two";
    });
```

Comment: Only works because you are using angular to bind the input box. What about a plugin that does stuff to the dom? You'd have to track all of those actions in a model too.

Comment: You are right, it doesn't work for manipulating DOM. I don't think angular route will work in this case. If you don't mind using plugin, ui-router will solve your problem.